# current time youtube embedded video

Tags: jquery, youtube

I will like to know if there's a way with Jquery or any other language to know the current time on a  youtube embedded video, if yes, How?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried something? http://bit.ly/MYacoh

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It depends on how you are embedding the YouTube video. But, in any case the JavaScript API has this function:

```
player.getCurrentTime()
```

Read:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference