# Return Embed YouTube Current Time

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

I know this question has already [been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166511/current-time-youtube-embedded-video), with answers pointing to [Google's iFrame API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)'s code `player.getCurrentTime():Number`, but where exactly do I put that JS code?

I want to append current time to `<p class="displaytime">` whenever `<button class="gettime">` is pressed.

I have already constructed the YT.Player object and am able to trigger Play and Pause with external buttons, but can't get Current Time.

Here's my trial with jQuery:

```
$('.gettime').click(function() {
$('.displaytime').append(player.getCurrentTime():Number);
});
```

I suppose I can't append the code directly?
Thanks!

Comment: show us the full code of the player

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it.

```
 $('.gettime').click(function(){
    var currenttime =  player['player1'].getCurrentTime();
    $('.displaytime').append(currenttime);
    });
```

I guess the `:Number` in API's ref code was to tell that the output is a number.